# Trying to use applet programming and want to print sum or product on particular event but several errors are occuring?

Tags: java, events, applet

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SumProduct extends Applet {

    public void init() {

        TextField txt1 = new TextField("");
        TextField txt2 = new TextField("");
    //TextField txt3= new TextField();
        Button p = new Button("Sum");
        Button q = new Button("Product");

        add(p);
        add(q);
        add(txt1);
        add(txt2);
    //add(txt3);
    }

    public Boolean action(Event e, Object args) {

        if (e.target == p) {
            r = a + b;
        }

        if (e.target == q) {
            r = a * b;
        }
    }

    public void print(Graphics g) {

        int a = 0, b = 0, r;
        String m;
        String s1 = txt1.getText();
        String s2 = txt2.getText();
        a = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        b = Integer.parseInt(s2);
        m = String.valueOf(r);

        g.drawString(m, 100, 75);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add more information. What are the errors you get?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing. 3) What is your question?  (And no, adding a '?' to the title does not make it a question.)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `r` in `print` but try to use it in `action` This code will not compile.

Try moving `r` to be a field variable.